# How to write an EventBridge pattern for Security Hub specific resource type

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking to set up a Slack notification on a Security Hub finding, but only for ACM Certificate Resources. The path I am taking is EventBridge > SNS > Chatbot [image]

Something like this:

```
{
  "detail-type": ["Security Hub Findings - Imported"],
  "source": ["aws.securityhub"],
  "detail": {
    "findings": {
      "Workflow": {
        "Status": ["NEW"]
      },
      "ResourceType": ["AWS::ACM::Certificate"]
    }
  }
}
```

Under `ResourceType` I have tried `AwsCertificateManagerCertificate` (Type in the Security Hub Findings menu) and `AWS::ACM::Certificate` (Resource Type in AWS Config resource)

If I get rid of `ResourceType` it's all great and Slack comes up with a notification if I change the Workflow Status from NEW > NOTIFIED > NEW